# Once logged in how to display username or first or last name php?

Tags: php, authentication

I'm making a login system and I'm trying to make it once the user is logged in it will display the users username or first name. I figured out how to display the ID of the user but I want the username (uid is how I have it setup) or first name (first is how I have it set up).

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
    echo "<div class='welcome_login'><h1>Welcome! Thanks for logging in!!</h1></div>";
} else {
    echo "<div class='intro_page'><h1>You must login or signup!</h1></div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: When you say _set up_ do you mean you are storing the `username` and `firstname` in the PHP session variable?

Comment: You have to have `session_start();` at the top of all pages using sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a database lookup for the user that have the id stored in the session $_SESSION['id'] or you can store the user firstname and lastname as an array in the session :

```
$user = [ 'firstname' => "user firstname queried from database",
          'lastname' => "user lastname queried from database"
        ]
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

then you can do

```
echo "<div class='welcome_login'><h1>Welcome!",$_SESION['user']['firstname'] ," Thanks for logging in!!</h1></div>";
```

i recommend you see this tutorial : 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE134D877783367C7

for a great login and registration system

Comment: I do have the session_start(); at the top of the page but I just didn't copy all of the code just where I was trying to echo out the info. I'll check out that tutorial! Php is different than Ruby-Rails for sure!

Comment: totally different